# Angular menu have routing not woking

Tags: angular, routes, menu

I have a menu with two links, it should take me to those two components, but they are not showing at all. The routing is very basic, two components and an empty route, i have been following the tutorials i´ve seen, your help and patience will be very appreciated.

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { HorasComponent } from './horas/horas.component';
import { ServicioComponent } from './servicio/servicio.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ServicioComponent },
  { path: 'servicio', component: ServicioComponent },
  { path: 'horas', component: HorasComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
        <h1>Calculadora</h1>
        <span class="menu-spacer"></span>
        <div>
            <a mat-button routerLink="/servicio" routerLinkActive="active"> Servicio </a>
            <a mat-button routerLink="/horas" routerLinkActive="active"> Horas </a>
        </div>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatToolbarModule } from  '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatIconModule } from  '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatSidenavModule } from  '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatListModule } from  '@angular/material/list';
import { MatButtonModule } from  '@angular/material/button';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { ServicioComponent } from './servicio/servicio.component';
import { HorasComponent } from './horas/horas.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    AppComponent,
    ServicioComponent,
    HorasComponent,
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule
    
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Is there something missing?

Comment: Try without the slash (e.g routerLink="servicio") and also check the console for errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { HorasComponent } from './horas/horas.component';
import { ServicioComponent } from './servicio/servicio.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ServicioComponent },
  { path: 'horas', component: HorasComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.module.ts** is same as yours.

**app.component.html**

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

**Servicio.component.html**

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
<mat-toolbar-row>
    <h1>Calculadora</h1>
    <span class="menu-spacer"></span>
    <div>
        <a mat-button routerLink="" routerLinkActive="active"> Servicio </a>
        <a mat-button routerLink="horas" routerLinkActive="active"> Horas </a>
    </div>
</mat-toolbar-row>
```